# Storing location codes in Solr and retrieving back the mapped location names?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to store address data in Solr. I originally use MariaDB to store and process everything but I also require a lot of complex searching and use Solr in addition to MariaDB. To reduce size requirement and data redundancy, I decided to store location codes instead of the location name. I have a file which contains a static mapping of codes to location names. Is there any way to store these values as codes in Solr, and somehow retrieve those values as location name text and not location codes (numbers)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So instead of having the search return the relevant data, you're looking to look at each entry up in MariaDB for each location code for each entry? I'd usually recommend against that strategy, unless the data stored is on the larger side (i.e. raw binary files). For single fields such as location name, store it in Solr. The storage requirement will be larger, but storage is cheaper than processing - and scales far better.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid. Location code and name mapping are not stored in the database, but in some files, and some of them are hardcoded into code. So you are saying is, I should just lookup the codes first before submitting it to Solr?

Comment: Yes. Let Solr have the required information present instead of having to look it up later. It'll make life simpler.

Comment: Alright then, thanks